# Adding numbers in GUI giving unexpected result?

Tags: java, user-interface

The following is a simple code that takes in two numbers and adds them in a gui. For some reason the output is not the sum of the two numbers, but is instead a random number. Please tell me what is going on. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number");
        String sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number");

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(fn); //Converts a string into an integer, since showInputDialog can only take in a string
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(fn);

        int sum = num1 + num2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer is "+sum, "This is the title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```

For example, if I enter the first and second numbers as 5 and 6 respectively, instead of an outcome of 11 I get an outcome of 10. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're adding `fn` to `fn` -> `int num2 = Integer.parseInt(fn);`, which should be `int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sn);` ...

Comment: Oh, this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a random number, it should be double the first number because num2 is also `fn`

```
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(fn);
```

This is likely a typo and should be:

```
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sn);
```

Things like this are why you should name variables properly. ie. `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` it improves readability vastly and will likely result in it being easier to spot typos like this.